# how to stop song on toggle button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is the shortcode for play song on toggle button and my problem is when I click the toggle button to pause the music did not paused**

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';    
import './audio.css';
import music from './BLOOD.mp3';

const PlaySong = () => {
var song = new Audio(music);
const [playMusic, setPlayMusic] = useState(false);
const handlePlayMusic = () => {
let state = !playMusic;
setPlayMusic(state);
console.log(state);
if(state === true){
song.play()
} else {
song.pause();  // the song did not stop when I call this method I don't 
know why        
}
}
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="button r" id="button-4">
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" onChange= 
            {handlePlayMusic} />
            <div className="knobs" />
            <div className="layer" />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default PlaySong
```

Comment: Please try to make an effort on the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's working and that is the code:

```
const [activeSong, setActiveSong] = useState(false);
var [saveSong, setSaveSong] = useState({});

var drake = {
    value: 3,
    name: 'Energy',
    artist: 'Drake',
    audio: music, // I get it from import music './song.mp3'
};

function handlePlayPause() {
    let states = !activeSong;
    setActiveSong(states);

    if (states) {  
        playSong(drake); // load song and play it
    }
    else {
        togglePause(saveSong); // pause song
    }

}

function playSong(drake) {
    var Song = new Audio(drake.audio);
    Song.play();
    setSaveSong(Song);
    return Song;
}

function togglePause(saveSong) {
    saveSong.pause();
    setSaveSong({});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `playMusic` state is always `false` meaning that your `else` block in `handlePlayMusic()` method will never be reached. You need to call `setPlayMusic` to toggle the state after playing/pausing.

Also, you don't need two variables for one single state, so you don't need `state` variable.

Suggested code:

```js
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

const handlePlayClick = () => {
  setPlaying(prevPlaying => {
    if (prevPlaying) {
      song.pause();
    } else {
      song.play(); // might need to consider calling `resume`
    }

    return !prevPlaying;
  });
};
```

Comment: I try your way but also still not working!!

Comment: first of all, does `pause` method exist in the `song` object? second, did you connect the event to the method I added? to be sure, just add some `console.log`s inside the `pause` block and see if it's actually called.

Comment: yes, pause exists in the song object and also I try to do some alerts when the song should be paused and I get the alert so it gets inside that if.

Comment: I did console.log(song.pause()), and it's give me undefined why?